# MicrosoftIdentityWebApi still trying to validate Audience when turned off

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, authorization, webapi

I have a .NET WebAPI app that we want to turn off the Audience validation on the Bearer token. For whatever reason, the following code *still* returns an Audience validation error. I suspect it's something to do with the sequence of where this code lives, but I've tried a few other options that end up throwing errors downstream.

**This code returns an Audience Validation error**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => { }, options =>
                {
                    options.TenantId = azureConfig["TenantId"];
                    options.Instance = azureConfig["Instance"];
                    options.ClientId = azureConfig["ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = azureConfig["ClientSecret"];
                    options.Domain = azureConfig["Domain"];
                    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
                });
```

**This code throws a null exception in `System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write`**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options => { }, options =>
    {
        options.Instance = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")["Instance"];
        options.ClientId = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")["ClientId"];
        options.Domain = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")["Domain"];
        options.TenantId = configuration.GetSection("AzureAd")["TenantId"];
    });

builder.Services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
});
```

I believe the last snippet is probably due to the timing in which it gets there. Has anyone been able to successfully turn this off?